# bios and real mode

Tags: operating-system, x86, kernel, bios

It is said that bios program can only be seen in real mode, it is also known that bios is stored in ROM, but what the CPU maps is RAM usually, does it mean in real mode, some space of the memory is mapped to ROM, so we can see the bios program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The physical address space is more than just RAM. It contains ROM and memory-mapped devices, such as APICs and video memory. The main reason you cannot use the BIOS from outside of real mode is that it was written to be used in real mode. Some functions may work in 16-bit protected mode, and more will work in Virtual 8086 mode, but trying to call the wrong function could cause your system to crash. Also, interrupts work differently in protected mode than real mode, so you would have to remap the functions.

Another reason the BIOS could be unavailable outside of real mode is paging. Paging is the process of mapping virtual addresses to physical addresses. If the operating system uses paging, it could choose not to map the pages containing ROM into virtual memory at all, so they would effectively not be there, and therefore impossible to call. ROM still takes some of the physical address space, but is unavailable through virtual memory.

Comment: What does it mean that "it was written to be used in real mode."?

Comment: @venus.w Real mode acts very differently than protected mode in some ways. The biggest differences are how memory is accessed and the default address and operand sizes. The BIOS was written to be run in real mode, so it uses the real mode versions of these. Trying to run the same binary data in a different mode could produce some very odd effects. When that happens, an exception is the best result possible.

Comment: Is bios rom, gdt, idt usually stored or mapped to the bottom 1M.

Comment: They can be anywhere (or nowhere except for the IDT) in virtual memory. In physical memory, ROM is always in the same place (0xA0000-0xFFFFF). The GDT and IDT could be anywhere, but are likely to be in the first 1MB since that is the only space addressable in real mode.